# How can I pass multiple parameters to identify a page?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I currently have one question and that is if I can pass 2 parameters in my url to identify a page.

Currently I have this code, which gets me through the parameter "url_slug" my post stored in the database.

```
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/controllers/posts.php');

function selectPostBySlug($slug)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM animales WHERE url_slug like ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = executeQuery($sql, [$slug]);
    $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
    return $records;
}

if (isset($_GET['url_slug'])){
    $url_slug= preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', '-', trim(strtolower($_GET["url_slug"])));
           
    $episode = selectPostBySlug($url_slug);
}
?>
```

So far everything works fine for me, but I would like to add that when I get the "url_slug" parameter I also get an extra parameter to identify the post more accurately, for example in the database.

[DATABASE IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjoQF.png)

Currently the urls work this way => `localhost/animales?url_slug=oso`

**-----**

but since I added the new "tipo" column I would like the url to identify the posts this way => `localhost/animales?url_slug=oso&tipo=panda` | and send me to the post panda

and when I enter to = `localhost/animales?url_slug=oso&tipo=polar` |  send me to the post polar

**EDIT:**

```
function executeQuery($sql, $data)
{
    global $conn;
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $values = array_values($data);
    $types = str_repeat('s', count($values));
    $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$values);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt;
}
```

Comment: You can get "tipo" and pass param "tipo" to function selectPostBySlug and write a query again. Look like : Select * from animales where url_slug like "aaa" and tipo like "bbbb"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `tipo` parameter to your `selectPostBySlug` and do the same thing fot the `tipo` query

```
//                             3. Added: Parameter to handle Tipo Filter
//                              vvvvvvv
function selectPostBySlug($slug, $tipo)
{
    global $conn;
    //                         4. Added: Additional Condition to Handle `tipo` filter
    //                                                   vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM animales WHERE url_slug like ? AND tipo like ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = executeQuery($sql, [$slug, $tipo]);
    //                               ^^^^^^^
    //                        5. Added: Assign `tipo` input from function parameter
    $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
    return $records;
}
//                 0. Added: Condition to check if `tipo` query exists
//                           vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
if (isset($_GET['url_slug']) && isset($_GET['tipo'])){
    $url_slug= preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', '-', trim(strtolower($_GET["url_slug"])));
    // 1. Added: Tipo Input Filter
    $tipo= preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', '-', trim(strtolower($_GET["tipo"])));
           
    $episode = selectPostBySlug($url_slug, $tipo);
//                                        ^^^^^^^^
//                                      2. Added: for Tipo Filter

}
```

Comment: Hello thanks for answering, I am trying with your code but it is giving me the following error and I cannot find the problem | Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '? LIMIT 1' at line 1 mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM a...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\database\db.php(115): executeQuery('SELECT * FROM a...', Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\ver.php(9): selectPostBySlug('oso', 'polar') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\database\db.php on line 17

Comment: can you send the `executeQuery` function?

Comment: Yes, I just edited the question by adding the function

Comment: Try to change `AND tipo like ?` to `AND tipo = ?`